# Is there an ideal mode of communication for resigning from a Remote Job?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, telecommute

Usually when I quit my job, I walk up to my boss and hand them a letter.

I like the personal touch of being able to do it face-to-face, and usually when an employee stops by your office with a letter in hand you have some idea where the conversation is going, so its no great surprise.

But when working a remote job, I am not so sure. My options are :

- Send an Email
- Send him a message on our Instant Message system
- Request a time to call him and do it via phone call

My main concerns are that he is very busy. He gets many emails, which can sometimes get ignored, however I wouldn't like to surprise him via a call or chat message. Also, calls and chat messages do not carry the same kind of permanent paper trail that a written letter would for the HR file.

Is there an ideal mode of communication for resigning from a Remote Job?

Comment: Personally I'd try to do it by phone, but also write a letter out and make sure HR gets a copy at some point after the phone conversation.

Comment: As I understand it a written resignation letter only needs to be provided if the company explicitly asks for one. An electronic trail is generally more permanent than a paper copy.

Answer (score 3):

Send him an email requesting a meeting a phone meeting. If your boss has an assistant you can probably CC him/her so that the email won’t get lost in your boss’s inbox. If you don’t get a reply within a few hours then either a follow-up email or phone call.

During the phone meeting, remind your boss that you will be sending the resignation letter via email as an attachment.